# Grails: On 404 error need to know name of controller and action that caused it

Tags: grails

In the URL mapping file, i have connected 404 error with ErrorController's notFound action.

```
class UrlMappings {
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "500"(controller: "errorPage", action: "internalError")
    "403"(controller: "errorPage", action: "forbidden")
    "404"(controller: "errorPage", action: "notFound") 
}
```

If any controller does not makes render call and a default view does not exists for that action, it invokes the notFound action of ErrorPageController. Now, I want to know in this notFound action which action was called due to which the 404 exception was invoked. How can that be known? For example, in case of 500, the internalError action get request.exception through which we know what happened that invoked internalError. Same needs to be done for 404 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried this controller:

```
package test
class ErrorPageController {
    def grailsUrlMappingsHolder
    def grailsApplication

    def notFound() {
        // retrieve uri without context (if any)
        def uri = request.forwardURI - "/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}"

        // try to parse uri agains defined urlMappings to get parameters
        def parameters = grailsUrlMappingsHolder.match(uri)?.parameters ?: [:]
        [previousAction : parameters.action, previousController: parameters.controller]
    }
}
```

I have assumed that in your path the context is your `appName`, you may have to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: request.forwardURI... this was what i missed.. thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use grails wildcard filters like mentioned http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html

Then print the things you need like controllername and action here. The filter get called before every controller / action execution.

Comment: i already have filters setup. The filter get called before the redirect to notFound action so there is no way to know at filter whether current request will result in 404 error. Also, i dont want to print i want to store the controller and action name that resulted in notFound in notFound action itself.